# I want to disable global messages on magento

Tags: php, magento, popup

Does anyone have any idea how i can disable global messages on magento 1.12??

I can't make them work the way I want so I would rather disable them until I can make them work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to remove them from layout. You need to put into any layout xml file the following code

```
<default>
   <remove name="global_messages" />
   <remove name="messages" />
</default>
```

Comment: ...preferably in a *local.xml* file in the *layout* folder of your site's custom theme.